# Flask Admin on postgres database view

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-admin

Is there a way I can create admin view on Flask-Admin on a database view? I'm using Postgres, and have created a view, let's take the below one as example:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS (
    SELECT id, name, age, score
    FROM student
);
```

If I want to setup admin view for that, how would I do it?

I tried creating an abstract model for it:

```
class StudentView(sqa.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    __tablename__ = 'test_view'

    id = sqa.Column(sqa.Integer)
    name = sqa.Column(sqa.String)
    age = sqa.Column(sqa.Integer)
    score = sqa.Column(sqa.Integer)
```

And added admin view like this:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class StudentViewAdmin(ModelView):
    _model = models.StudentView
```

Registering this admin view to admin:

```
admin.add_view(admin_views.StudentViewAdmin(admin_views.DashboardView123._model, db.session))
```

But, I'm getting following error, while adding the view to admin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    setup_admin(app)
  File "/Users/rohitjain/app.py", line 35, in setup_admin
    admin.add_view(admin_views.StudentViewAdmin(admin_views.StudentViewAdmin._model, db.session))
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 318, in __init__
    menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 771, in __init__
    self._refresh_cache()
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 847, in _refresh_cache
    self._list_columns = self.get_list_columns()
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 979, in get_list_columns
    only_columns=self.column_list or self.scaffold_list_columns(),
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 404, in scaffold_list_columns
    for p in self._get_model_iterator():
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 340, in _get_model_iterator
    return model._sa_class_manager.mapper.iterate_properties
AttributeError: type object 'StudentView' has no attribute '_sa_class_manager'
```

Can we actually do this? I've done this in Django, setting up admin for a postgres db view, but am unable to setup the same in Flask till now. Any leads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason to create an abstract model? `__abstract__` attribute set to `True` is the cause of this error. If you don't subclass from this model you don't need it:

```
class StudentView(sqa.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test_view'

    id = sqa.Column(sqa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sqa.Column(sqa.String)
    age = sqa.Column(sqa.Integer)
    score = sqa.Column(sqa.Integer)
```

Also SQLAlchemy mapper needs a primary key (in model not in actual view). The application will treat your view as a table so it won't produce database errors as soon as it doesn't try to update the view.

Comment: Ah! Got it. Just made one of my columns a primary key in the model itself, and it worked. I see it's not needed to be primary key in view itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. Got the dashboard up and running. Looks like the previous answer was also correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would help if you were to post the rest of the file in which you define the model. You might be extending the wrong class(sqa.Model).

Your `ModelView` also has no columns listed. I think that might be required?

[Here's](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.7/db_sqla/) the `hello_world` documentation for flask_admin. You can see they explicitly specify columns, filters, and searchability in the `ModelView`.

**Excerpt:**

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128))

class UserView(ModelView):
    # Show only name and email columns in list view
    column_list = ('name', 'email')

    # Enable search functionality - it will search for terms in
    # name and email fields
    column_searchable_list = ('name', 'email')

    # Add filters for name and email columns
    column_filters = ('name', 'email')
```

Comment: Just to clarify my question again, I want to create ModelView on database view, not table. You're creating on normal table.

Comment: BTW, in postgres, a database view cannot have primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Admin view can be achieved with sandman library in **Python**.Here is the link for that [sandman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sandman)

Here's the code that uses flask-admin. But first you have to install library by command
**pip install sandman**

```
from sandman2 import app

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/testsmsmagic'
#path of your database.

from sandman2.model import activate

activate()

app.run(port=5999)
```

run that file after that you can see your admin portal on browser with `http://localhost:5999/admin`